# php doesnt read jquery indexOf?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

html

```
<nav class="main-navi">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html" >
                    Home
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="portfolio.html">
                    Portfolio
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">
                    About
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="service.html">
                    services
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blog.html">
                    Blog
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">
                    contacts
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em>
    </nav>
```

script

```
    <script>
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    $('.main-navi ul li a').each(function () {
        var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
        $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
    });
</script>
```

so without PHP its work perfect, but after i put php and the href change like this it wont work for reason that i dont know

html

```
<nav class="main-navi">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/index" >
                    Home
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/fotoportfolio">
                    Portfolio
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/fotoabout">
                    About
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/fotoservice">
                    services
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/fotoblog">
                    Blog
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?r=site/fotocontact">
                    contacts
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em>
    </nav>
```

for script

```
$this->registerJs('
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    $(".main-navi ul li a").each(function () {
    var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1;
    $(this).toggleClass("active", status);
});')
```

the class active not showing up? is there any mistake i make? im using Yii2 framework btw.and i use this code in main.php so the navbar will looping to other page

Comment: The last code block is lacking a `'` (see how the end of the color is red). Is it a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: sorry lack of copypaste i have ') honestly but still not working. i use this code in main.php so the navbar will looping to other page

Answer (score 0):

You got the strings reversed. You should be checking for this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var loc = window.location.pathname;
   $(".main-navi ul li a").each(function () {
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      var status = href.indexOf(loc) > -1;
      $(this).toggleClass("active", status);
   }
 });
```

Comment: already test it too sir. but doesnt effect anything. is it because i put it in main? and when i put with php i use your code from the start

Comment: try my edited answer. It will ensure the code is executed after the page loads, otherwise your a tags might not exist yet in the document. If that doesn't work it's probably worth checking what console.log(status) says.

Comment: ill try your code tonight sir, quick question if change the name file to hompage.php but still href to ?r=site/index. is it the reason?